# Adding extra calculated column to view, which is not present in table

Tags: sql, view

I want to create view with union of three tables. But in result query I want one extra column.

My code is like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DISCOUNT
AS SELECT 
* FROM
(
SELECT 
    T1.ID,
    T1.AMOUNT,
    T1.ITEM,
    T1.DATA,
    T1.DISC_PERCENT,
    T4.UOM AS(SELECT UomCode 
                     FROM T4
                     JOIN Table5 T5 ON T4.UomEntry = T5.UomEntry
                     JOIN Table6 T6 on T6.UgpEntry = T4.UgpEntry
                     where T6.ITEM = T1.ITEM
                     and T5.UomEntry = T6.PriceUnit)
FROM Table1 T1,Table4 T4
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    T2.ID,
    T2.AMOUNT,
    T2.ITEM,
    T2.DATA,
    T2.DISC_PERCENT,
    T4.UOM AS(SELECT UomCode 
                     FROM T4
                     JOIN Table5 T5 ON T5.UomEntry = T4.UomEntry
                     JOIN Table6 T6 on T6.UgpEntry = T4.UgpEntry
                     where T6.ITEM = T1.ITEM
                     and T5.UomEntry = T6.PriceUnit)
FROM Table2 T2
UNION ALL
SELECT
    T3.ID,
    T3.BILLAMOUNT,
    T3.DATA,
    T3.BUSINESSCODE,
    T3.DISC_PERCENT  
FROM Table3 T3
);
```

Already so in the points where I have the select nested sql management signals me of errors, I have not the faintest idea how to solve

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The code is not syntactically correct, so you should work on that before adding new columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can just project a null value to make all groups having same number of columns As below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DISCOUNT
AS SELECT 
* FROM
(
SELECT 
    T1.ID,
    T1.AMOUNT,
    T1.ITEM,
    T1.DATA,
    T1.DISC_PERCENT,
    T4.UOM AS(SELECT UomCode 
                     FROM T4
                     JOIN Table5 T5 ON T4.UomEntry = T5.UomEntry
                     JOIN Table6 T6 on T6.UgpEntry = T4.UgpEntry
                     where T6.ITEM = T1.ITEM
                     and T5.UomEntry = T6.PriceUnit)
FROM Table1 T1,Table4 T4
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    T2.ID,
    T2.AMOUNT,
    T2.ITEM,
    T2.DATA,
    T2.DISC_PERCENT,
    T4.UOM AS(SELECT UomCode 
                     FROM T4
                     JOIN Table5 T5 ON T5.UomEntry = T4.UomEntry
                     JOIN Table6 T6 on T6.UgpEntry = T4.UgpEntry
                     where T6.ITEM = T1.ITEM
                     and T5.UomEntry = T6.PriceUnit)
FROM Table2 T2
UNION ALL
SELECT
    T3.ID,
    T3.BILLAMOUNT,
    T3.DATA,
    T3.BUSINESSCODE,
    T3.DISC_PERCENT  
     Null AS UOM
FROM Table3 T3
) ;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!